# Pandas: Change a value into a word

Tags: python, pandas

what should I do if I want to change the value 1.0 in a dataframe to word 'T'

```
| loan   |
| ------ |
| 1.0    |
| 1.0    |

to

| loan |
| ---- |
| T    |
| T    |
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for a dataframe with a single column :

```
df.replace(1, "T", inplace=True)
```

Otherwise, use [**`pandas.Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead to specify the column name :

```
df['loan'] = df['loan'].replace(1, "T")
```